# Excepción lanzada por la clase de aplicación 'com.sun.jersey.spi.container.servlet.WebComponent.service:420'

Tags: java, rest, maven, retrofit

Estoy intentando consumir un servicio Rest en Java a través de http3 y retrofit y cuando intento realizar la llamada me sale lo siguiente:

```
[ERROR   ] The exception contained within MappableContainerException could not be mapped to a response, re-throwing to the HTTP container
okhttp3.HttpUrl.get(Ljava/lang/String;)Lokhttp3/HttpUrl;
[ERROR   ] SRVE0777E: Excepción lanzada por la clase de aplicación 'com.sun.jersey.spi.container.servlet.WebComponent.service:420'
javax.servlet.ServletException: java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: okhttp3.HttpUrl.get(Ljava/lang/String;)Lokhttp3/HttpUrl;
    at com.sun.jersey.spi.container.servlet.WebComponent.service(WebComponent.java:420)
    at com.sun.jersey.spi.container.servlet.ServletContainer.service(ServletContainer.java:538)
    at com.sun.jersey.spi.container.servlet.ServletContainer.service(ServletContainer.java:716)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:668)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.servlet.ServletWrapper.service(ServletWrapper.java:1230)
    at [internal classes]
    at es.xxxxx.n005.rest.swagger.CORSFilter.doFilter(CORSFilter.java:71)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.filter.FilterInstanceWrapper.doFilter(FilterInstanceWrapper.java:201)
    at [internal classes]
Caused by: java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: okhttp3.HttpUrl.get(Ljava/lang/String;)Lokhttp3/HttpUrl;
    at retrofit2.Retrofit$Builder.baseUrl(Retrofit.java:470)
    at es.xxxxx.n005.teneoonline.client.TeneoOnlineClient.setupRestClient(TeneoOnlineClient.java:43)
    at es.xxxxx.n005.teneoonline.client.TeneoOnlineClient.<clinit>(TeneoOnlineClient.java:28)
    at es.xxxxx.n005.services.DatosGestionDCWSImpl.buscarGestorDC(DatosGestionDCWSImpl.java:128)
    at es.xxxxx.n005.services.comun.MenuPrincipalWSImpl.bifurcacion(MenuPrincipalWSImpl.java:61)
    at es.xxxxx.n005.rest.api.SalesforceApi.main_menu(SalesforceApi.java:82)
    at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor642.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at com.sun.jersey.spi.container.JavaMethodInvokerFactory$1.invoke(JavaMethodInvokerFactory.java:60)
    at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.model.method.dispatch.AbstractResourceMethodDispatchProvider$ResponseOutInvoker._dispatch(AbstractResourceMethodDispatchProvider.java:205)
    at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.model.method.dispatch.ResourceJavaMethodDispatcher.dispatch(ResourceJavaMethodDispatcher.java:75)
    at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.uri.rules.HttpMethodRule.accept(HttpMethodRule.java:302)
    at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.uri.rules.RightHandPathRule.accept(RightHandPathRule.java:147)
    at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.uri.rules.ResourceClassRule.accept(ResourceClassRule.java:108)
    at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.uri.rules.RightHandPathRule.accept(RightHandPathRule.java:147)
    at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.uri.rules.RootResourceClassesRule.accept(RootResourceClassesRule.java:84)
    at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.application.WebApplicationImpl._handleRequest(WebApplicationImpl.java:1480)
    at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.application.WebApplicationImpl._handleRequest(WebApplicationImpl.java:1411)
    at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.application.WebApplicationImpl.handleRequest(WebApplicationImpl.java:1360)
    at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.application.WebApplicationImpl.handleRequest(WebApplicationImpl.java:1350)
    at com.sun.jersey.spi.container.servlet.WebComponent.service(WebComponent.java:416)
    ... 8 more

[ERROR   ] EXCEPCION ServletException: java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: okhttp3.HttpUrl.get(Ljava/lang/String;)Lokhttp3/HttpUrl;
```

Éste es el metodo que utilizo:

```
private static void setupRestClient() throws ECIException {
        
        OkHttpClient.Builder httpClient = new OkHttpClient.Builder();
        httpClient.connectTimeout(90, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
        httpClient.readTimeout(90, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
        httpClient.writeTimeout(90, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
                
        try{
            Retrofit retrofit = new Retrofit.Builder().baseUrl(ConfiguracionInfo.getStrUrlTeneoOnLine())
                    .addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create())
                    .client(httpClient.build()).build();
            REST_CLIENT = retrofit.create(TeneoOnlineService.class);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            log.error("[TeneoOnlineClient] Error al generar el cliente REST");
            throw new ECIException(ECIError.E027);
        }
    }
```

Y estas las dependencias en pom.xml:

```
 <dependency>
        <groupId>com.google.code.gson</groupId>
        <artifactId>gson</artifactId>
        <version>2.8.5</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.squareup.retrofit2</groupId>
        <artifactId>retrofit</artifactId>
        <version>2.6.2</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.squareup.retrofit2</groupId>
        <artifactId>converter-gson</artifactId>
        <version>2.6.2</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.squareup.okhttp3</groupId>
        <artifactId>okhttp</artifactId>
        <version>3.9.0</version>
    </dependency>
  </dependencies>
```

He estado revisando foros como dependencias y versiones de retrofit pero no he conseguido nada claro por mi parte.

¿Me podéis ayudar? En caso de haber otra opción agradecería que se me indicara.

Si necesitáis más información no dudéis en pedírmelo.

Muchas gracias.

Comment: No es Android, lo siento

Answer (score 0, accepted):

En general, este error indica que una librería espera encontrar una versión de una librería pero encuentra otra (generalmente otra de una versión anterior).

En este caso te indica que una clase de retrofit llama a un método de una clase de okhttp3 que no existe.

Lo primero sería buscar la documentación de dependencias de tus librerías y revisarlas. En maven suele ser sencillo, por ejemplo yendo a la página de retrofit 2.6.2 (https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.squareup.retrofit2/retrofit/2.6.2) ves en la lista de dependencias una dependencia a okhttp3 **versión 3.12.0**.

Actualiza tu dependencia de okhttp3 a 3.12.0 como mínimo.

Si no tuvieras esto, tendrías que ir subiendo la versión de la librería afectada hasta encontrar una que funcione.

Por supuesto, otra opción sería en vez de incrementar la versión de okhttp3, usar una versión de retrofit anterior. Pero si no hay motivo en contra, cuanto más actualizadas tus librerías mejor.

Comment: Muchas gracias. Actualizé a la 3.12.0 y ya no me da problemas por esto.